# How do I run a CRM 2011 custom workflow activity as a privileged user?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to be able to make one user temporarily mirror another on demand. The mirroring user should get the same business unit, teams, and roles as the target user. Right now it is done manually, but it's a pain. I wrote a custom workflow activity to do it and it works if I run it as a system administrator and pick a mirroring user and target user.

But the end goal is to be able to allow certain users to run the dialog themselves. If I try to run it with myself as the mirroring user I get an error saying I don't have the privilege to assign roles, which makes sense since the workflow takes away my roles and then tries to assign me the target user's roles.

I'd like for the workflow activity to run as a privileged user but haven't had any luck so far. I've tried creating the `IOrganizationService` like this:

```
var context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
var serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
```

According to the documentation calling `CreateOrganizationService` with `null` as the parameter should force the user of the System user but it appears to still be running as the calling user.

I also tried calling `CreateOrganizationService` and passing the Guid of a different user with the System Administrator role, but got the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflows has special conditions and is designed to ignore the guid you pass to the CreateOrganizationService.

I take the next paragraph from this [article](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.pt/2011/05/processesworkflow-ownership-faqs.html):

> For the automatic workflow case, the owner of the workflow is also the
>   person who activates it and who selects the trigger mechanism and the
>   workflow steps so it is OK if the workflow executes under that user’s
>   context. For the on-demand case, a user is specifically requesting
>   some actions to be performed on his behalf by a workflow so the user
>   is fully aware of the workflow definition and that it will execute;
>   therefore it is safe to execute the workflow under that user’s context
>   instead of the workflow owner (who might not be aware that a user
>   requests an on-demand execution).

Answer (score 2):

1. The custom workflow activity could be converted to a plug-in registered to run in the context of CRM Service or an Administrator
2. The workflow could be automatically, rather than manually triggered

   - If the end users are explicitly starting the workflow, it will be running in their user context
   - Dialogs are always run in the initiating users context
   - A workflow triggered by an event rather than being explicitly started by the user will run in the context of the user who started, and owns, the workflow - in this case an Administrator
   - A dialog or custom ribbon button could change something (a custom field) on the record that your custom workflow activity is registered to execute on-change